# In what direction does mongoengine reverse_delete_rule work?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

If I have the following two models:

```
class User(Document):
    ...

class Profile(Document):
    user = ReferenceField(reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
```

Does deleting a User instance delete its Profile? Does deleting its Profile delete the user?

There seams to be an error in the [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html#dealing-with-deletion-of-referred-documents):

> ```
> class Employee(Document):
>     ...
>     profile_page = ReferenceField('ProfilePage', reverse_delete_rule=mongoengine.NULLIFY)
> ```
>
> The declaration in this
>   example means that when an Employee object is removed, the ProfilePage
>   that belongs to that employee is removed as well. If a whole batch of
>   employees is removed, all profile pages that are linked are removed as
>   well.

The code uses `NULLIFY`, but the explanation indicates the use of `CASCADE`. or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting a User instance deletes its Profile. This is the way `reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE` works. Just like in Relational Databases.

You may check this code:

```
from mongoengine import connect, Document, ReferenceField, CASCADE


connect('test_cascade')


class User(Document):
    pass


class Profile(Document):
    user = ReferenceField(User, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)


user = User().save()
profile = Profile(user=user).save()

user.delete()

assert Profile.objects.count() == 0
```

They also updated documentation, now it's other way around:

> ```
> class ProfilePage(Document):
>     ...
>     employee = ReferenceField('Employee', reverse_delete_rule=mongoengine.CASCADE)
> ```
>
> The declaration in this example means that when an **Employee object is removed**, the **ProfilePage that references that employee is removed as well**. If a whole batch of employees is removed, all profile pages that are linked are removed as well.